# How best to achieve ucwords($str," '-") using mb_convert_case with string like o'hare?

Tags: php

The following code:

```
<?php

$str = "tom o'hare mcdonald-wittern";
$utf = mb_convert_case ( $str ,MB_CASE_TITLE , "UTF-8" );
$words = ucwords($str," '-");

echo $utf;
echo "\r\n";
echo $words;
```

Results in output:

```
Tom O'hare Mcdonald-Wittern
Tom O'Hare Mcdonald-Wittern
```

I am doing a massive import of UTF-8 text, and although mb_convert_case seems to work almost as well as ucwords with the provided delimiters list, it seems to miss the H after the ' in o'hare.

I am using php 7.4.  How can I achieve the same result with mb_convert_case that I can easily get with the above syntax using uc_words?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use ucwords in this case?

Comment: The top comment in the docs addresses this exact issue. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case

Comment: thanks @Sammitch I tested out the function and it does do the job.